# Loading a large number of JSON files from GoogleCloudStorage to GoogleBigQuery

Tags: ruby, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I vacuumed log data from PostgreSQL by ruby scipt and stored into GoogleCloudStorage.
Each file has a 10000 of user data and the total number of files are over 100000.Belows are part of files.
[image: part of the files]

I downloaded each file into local machine and filtered gzip into JSON for BigQuery like
 `jq -c ".[]" ~/Downloads/1-10000 > ~/Downloads/1-10000.json`
and
 `bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON userdata.user_logs_1-10000 gs://user-logs/1-10000 schema.json`
 into BigQuery by hand.It succeed but this is not smart way and I can't repeat this.

What is a best way to parse a huge amount of gzip file into json and load into BigQuery at once.

I am open to all suggestions.Thank you.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" along with it's linked pages and "[mcve]". We need to see your effort, what code did you write? The command-lines you used are not showing us your attempt to solve the problem using Ruby. I'd also recommend considering asking this on [su] as you can probably do this from the command-line. How big are the decompressed JSON files?

Comment: "It succeed but this is not smart way and I can't repeat this." It seems pretty smart to me. What isn't repeatable about it?

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing. What format are the files in GCS? e.g. JSON or CSV or other?...

Answer (score 1):

I realize there are 3 steps. (please let me know if I'm wrong.)

1. download gzip files
2. decompress gzip into json
3. upload into BigQuery

---

You can try [yajl-ruby](https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby) gem to finish the first two steps.

```
require 'uri'
require 'yajl/gzip'
require 'yajl/deflate'
require 'yajl/http_stream'

url = URI.parse("http://example.com/foo.json")
results = Yajl::HttpStream.get(url)
```

And have a look at [BigBroda](https://github.com/michelson/BigBroda) and [BigQuery](https://github.com/abronte/BigQuery). I've never used Google BigQuery before, I'm not sure which one works. You have to try it yourself.

This is an example:

```
bq = BigQuery::Client.new(opts)
bq.insert('table_name', results)
```

---

It would be helpful if using multithreading or multiprocessing since you have a huge amount of files.